# Feedback polynomial of 7-bit Linear Feedback Shift Register

Tags: algorithms, pseudo-random-generators

My friend gave me a question to solve. The question he asked me was: the following sequence has been generated by a 7-bit linear feedback shift register. He asked me to find the feedback polynomial. I went through some lectures on LFSR on youtube. But still I am unable to solve this. Can anyone point out how to approach or crack this kind of question?

> 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1

Comment: Repetition length is 105 and there is no sequence of more than seven 1 or zeros. So 7 bits LFSR is possible. You can try all combinations with a small program (only 128 polynomials possible) and find the LFSRs with lenght 105. You will then have to find the initial value. Et voilà !

Comment: I am getting answer as x^7 + x^6 + x^5 + x^1 + 1. Is this right?

Comment: Do not post the same question on multiple sites. And do not delete a question once it's been answered, that's rude towards the answerer.

Comment: [Also posted on Crypto.SE](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/33662/351).
Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The feedback polynomial is $x^7 + x^6 + x^5 + x^1 + 1$ and can be computed using the [Berlekamp-Massey algorithm](http://bma.bozhu.me/).

Answer (score 5):

There is a comprehensive and excellent answer in this earlier [“Cryptanalysis of Linear Feedback Shift Registers”](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5293/cryptanalysis-of-linear-feedback-shift-registers?rq=1) question. Alternatively, if you know the order of the recurrence is $n$, you can solve a linear system of the form
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{lllll}
z_i & z_{i+1} & \cdots  & z_{i+n-1} \\
z_{i+1} & z_{i+2} & \cdots  & z_{i+n} \\
 & & \vdots & & \\
z_{i+n} & z_{i+n+1} & \cdots & z_{i+2n-1} \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
c_n \\
c_{n-1}\\
\vdots\\
c_2\\
c_1
\end{array}
\right)
=
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
z_{i+n}\\
z_{i+n+1}\\
\vdots\\
z_{i+2n}\\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
where $(z_t)_{t \geq 1}$ are the sequence bits, and $i\geq 1$. Here $c_i$ are the recurrence coefficients, to be determined. This should be done over $GF(2)$ i.e., with mod 2 arithmetic.

If the recurrence is order $n$ then $c_n=1.$ If the recurrence is of lower order the system becomes singular and you need to work with a smaller square left upper submatrix.

The polynomial you want is $1+c_1 x+\ldots+c_n x^n.$

Note that the matrix method is of higher complexity than the recursive Berlekamp Massey algorithm in the linked question.

Answer (score 2):

Denote the sequence by $X_0,X_1,\ldots$. If the minimal polynomial is $x^7 + a_6 x^6 + \cdots + a_0 x^0$, then (by definition) for every $N$ it will hold that $X_{N+7} = a_6 X_{N+6} + \cdots + a_0 X_N$ (modulo 2). (Your definition may vary slightly.) Since the first few values are $1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0$, this implies that $0 = a_6 + a_4 + a_0$. Collect enough such equations and solve them to recover the minimal polynomial.

Comment: Thats how I did it! and got this  x^7 + x^6 + x^5 + x^1 + 1. Is this right???

Comment: I don't know, but I count on you to have solved the equations correctly.

Comment: CAn you please verify it?? is there any pre made tool to verify online???

Comment: No, I can't verify it. This is your TA's task.

Comment: Perhaps, but if so, I'm sure you can find them on your own.